# AngularJS 1.4 error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs based web application - I'm able to see following error in my browser console.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

The error is triggering when I input on a text field element which having 3 directive associated with it. And in one of directive having watch on that model and another directive is making http async call and 3rd directive doing formatting job.

Can anyone help me which is causing this error, even though my application is not blocking anything because this error. I would like to get rid of this error from console. And the same directive working fine with other input element where I have particular element with 3 directive combination is creating the above error thrown to console.

```
function m(ac, ad, ab, aa) {
        function Z(ae) {
            try {
               ae.apply(null, bQ.call(arguments, 1)) //This line throws error*
            } finally {
                if (D--,
                0 === D) {
                    for (; n.length; ) {
                        try {
                            n.pop()()
                        } catch (q) {
                            ab.error(q)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function X() {
            V();
            W()
        }
        function V() {
            q: {
                try {
                    E = Q.state;
                    break q
                } catch (q) {}
                E = void 0
            }
            E = fv(E) ? null : E;
            dz(E, J) && (E = J);
            J = E
        }
        function W() {
            if (C !== R.url() || P !== E) {
                C = R.url(),
                P = E,
                eS(N, function(q) {
                    q(R.url(), E)
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: post full error message,

Comment: Please include the relevant code. It's hard to debug the code of something we can't see.

Comment: Pls post whole source code

Answer (score 0):

I think that a variable named `apply` is undefined. You should give it a value

Comment: Re-read the error message _'Cannot read property 'apply' of __undefined__'_

Answer (score 0):

you said other input element is working fine with the 3 direcitve combination. so it means the problem is from the input element I guess..

and I need to see the whole source code too. please post it